# How to get full name of Port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am connecting an Arduino to my C# WinForm through a serial port. The name shown in the Windows Device Manager is "Arduino Uno (COM7)". But when I check the name shown my combobox where I am getting the comport list, then it is just COM7. I have tried a lot of examples shown on StackOverflow but non seem to work as desired. I just want my combo box to be populated with meaningfull stuff so I do not have to check device manager every time.

This is my code to find the comports.

```
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(ports);
```

This is my code to connect the Serial Port...

```
try
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
            serialPort1.Open();

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use WMI:

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort");
foreach (ManagementObject result in searcher.Get())
{
    // Look at result["Caption"].ToString() and result["DeviceID"].ToString()
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, it actually worked. This is my code now var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort");
            foreach (ManagementObject result in searcher.Get())
            {
                string Caption = result["Caption"].ToString();
                string deviceId = result["DeviceID"].ToString();
                comboBox1.Items.Add(Caption);
            }

Comment: But how do I change the code which connects to the serial port? As now the combobox does not read "COM7" but reads "Arduino Uno (COM7)"

Comment: You need to store the `deviceId`, and use that as the name of the COM port to connect to. The easiest way is probably to put a class rather than a string into your ComboBox, where the class has two properties (one for the device ID and one for the caption), and set `DisplayMember` on the ComboBox to tell it to show the caption. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.items?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks)

Comment: There is an issue. I connected the Arduino, and that shows on COM9. But I connected another device, and that is not showing, even though if I use the previous code it shows as COM8, I have rechecked. Why is the other device not showing with the new code? This other device is more important for me, and I can see it in the device manager even if it is not shown in the combobox list

Comment: Never mind, I solved it through another way. Thanks again.